# Trigger Google custom search engine with custom text input

Tags: node.js, web, google-custom-search

I want to add Google custom search engine for a website, how Google says you should do it is copying the script and the gcse tag, as it auto generates the input and the search button, that works just fine.

I want to trigger the search with another text input, is there a way to run the same script as if I've used the copy paste Google script, but with my own text box?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick for this.

HTML

```
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="q" class="hidden">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<input type="text" id="input2">
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
let form = document.querySelector('#form1');
let input1 = document.querySelector('#form1 input[type="text"]');
let input2 =  document.querySelector('#input2');

input2.addEventListener('change', function() {
  let value = input2.value;
  input1.value = value;

  form.submit();
})
```

Demo Link: https://codepen.io/riazahmed0147/pen/BMdJyG